# BOT won't take uipath orchestrator queue items after the 100 queue item count achieved, even the pagination value has been set

Tags: queue, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

I'm trying to change the status of queue items which is more than 100. But once after reading 100 items BOT won't pick up the rest of queue items even if the pagination value (skip) has been set to 100. Here I have added all the images for more information.

Note: I have used RE-Framework to build up the code

[image: This image shows how the properties set for Get Queue Item activity]

[image: This image shows how the status needs to be changed based on the given logic. The status can be changed either into 'Success' or 'Failed']

[image: This image shows how the pagination (skip) value will be incremented]

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue

There appears to be a Solution ( link below ) using Index
and Increment is when 100 Items are hit

Get Queue Items 100 record limit

```
forum.uipath.com/t/get-queue-items-100-record-limit/73676
```